# SQL list all duplicaties

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is the problem in the simplest possible way:

Suppose I have a database with 2 columns, c1 and c2. I would like to get a list of all rows where the value in c2 appears multiple times. For example:

```
c1  c2
1   4
2   3
3   4
```

I want the output to be:

```
c1  c2
1   4
3   4
```

Since only in these rows does the value in c2 appear more than once.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
group by c2
having count(c2)>1;
```

The problem is, this collapses into only a single row, either

```
c1  c2
3   4
```

or

```
c1  c2
1   4
```

However, since the values in c1 are unique, I want both rows to appear. How can I do this?

Comment: Is `c1` unique?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if you had an answer assuming it was unique that would still be very helpful

Comment: Well, you're half way to one possible solution. If you knew that JOINs could play a part, could you figure out the rest?

Comment: @Strawberry would a join solution be more efficient than the answer currently selected?

Comment: Probably. Easy to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extending your sql query

```
SELECT * from Table where C2 in 
(SELECT c2 FROM Table
group by c2
having count(c2)>1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT C2 FROM TABLE
group by c2
having count(c2)>1) B ON A.C2 = B.c2
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use a query of a query to get that.

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM
  (SELECT c1, c2, count(c2) AS B 
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY c2) AS A
      WHERE A.B > 1 
      ORDER BY A.c2, A.c1
```

@Eduardo Silva you're correct. The select needs to be from the original table:

```
SELECT c1, c2 
  FROM my_table
  WHERE c2 IN 
  (SELECT c2 
    FROM my_table 
    GROUP BY c2
    HAVING count(c2)>1)
      ORDER BY c2, c1
```

Comment: Hint: you *can*, but you definitely don't have to

Comment: That want work. You are selecting columns c1 and c2 and grouping only by c2

Answer (score 1):

i think this work, but there's probably a better way:

```
SELECT C1, C2 AS find_a_better_way FROM tbl WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE C2=find_a_better_way LIMIT 2) = 2;
```

Comment: I like the 'find_a_better_way' name :-)

Answer (score 1):

I this is reasonably elegant and will do the trick:

```
SELECT c1,c2 FROM test.`table`
WHERE c2 in (SELECT c2 FROM test.`table`
group by c2
having count(c2)>1);
```

Answer (score 1):

With EXISTS:

```
select * from table t
where exists (
  select 1 from table
  where c1 <> t.c1 and c2 = t.c2
)
```

Comment: That nice, I don't see 'exists' much these days :-)

Comment: Really? It is very efficient.

Comment: Yeah, I like it for data migration scripts, it groks nicely to see if a table or partition is populated.